# Can't figure out why Bootstrap Scrollspy isn't working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, scrollspy

I am trying to implement Bootstrap's scroll spy in my website but it isn't working at all! I have tried many things but I can't get it to work. I have a lot of custom CSS being applied to my navbar so I am not sure if that could be effecting anything. Anyways, this is what I have so far:

**HTML Code:**

*Body:*

```
<body id="home" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="0">
```

*Navbar:*

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-lg navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs-down">
    <!-- Navbar content -->
    <ul class="navul">
        <li class="nav-item navitem"><a class="nav-link navhref" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a class="navhref" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a class="navhref" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a class="navhref" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Harish</h2>
 </nav>
```

*The about section of my website:*

```
<div class="sections container-fluid">
    <h1 id="about" class="section-heading">About</h1>
    <img class="about-img" src="img/Harish.jpeg" alt="Harish's Picture">
    <p class="paragraph">Text about me.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**
*(Just in case some of the styling could be interfering with Bootstrap's Scrollspy.)*

```
/*Navbar*/

.navbar {
  background-color: #009Fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-lg {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-lg ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-lg ul li {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-lg h2 {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-family:  'Helvetica Neue', 'Raleway', 'arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navul {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navitem {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Helvetica Neue', 'arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navhref {
  color: #fff;
}

.navhref {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.navhref:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.navitem:hover,
.navhref:hover {
  color: #007Bc6;
}

.navlinks {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #009Fff;
}
```

Comment: Your `data-target` in the `body` tag is a class (i.e. `.navbar`) when it should make reference to the id (i.e. `#navbar`) - can you change that and see if that works?

Comment: @ochi thanks for your response :). I actually tried both the id and class selector but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your `<ul>` was missing `class="nav"`

Both elements have a required classname:

- `<nav class="navbar">`
- `<ul class="nav"`>

#### Your css is overriding the bootstrap.css, but I think you want a different nav type.

If you take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n9s3k0ys/2/, you'll note that the nav does not maintain any highlighting as you navigate through the page.

Upon changing the nav class to `navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top`, you'll see something closer to what you're going for, but...
http://jsfiddle.net/n9s3k0ys/3/

Upon removing your css, everything becomes more clear: 
http://jsfiddle.net/n9s3k0ys/4/

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, just one question. Should I be adding the class = "nav" to this? `<ul class="naval nav">` I have tried this but for some reason it still isn't working. Do you think it's something in my css in addition to the missing class name that is causing this error? Sorry if my question is really basic... I'm pretty new to html and css, and I'm coming from a swift/objective-c background.

Comment: You are exactly right, on both counts(`<ul class="naval nav">` AND your css is breaking the nav), plus one more problem... Your css is attempting to build the nav into a horizontal menu, but `hidden-xs-down` was also convlicting with both the scrollSpy nav AND some of your css. Please take a careful look at the fiddles I sent you, in particular, v3 http://jsfiddle.net/n9s3k0ys/3/ and v4 http://jsfiddle.net/n9s3k0ys/4/.  If you start from version 4, and make small iterative css changes to get the look and feel you want, you'll wind up with exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help again, which nav type is the `hidden-xs-down` for?

Comment: I misstyped, but have correct my comment. Have you looked at http://jsfiddle.net/n9s3k0ys/4/ ?

Comment: Yup, and I will try to narrow it down and get this working. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: What are you trying to get the nav to do?

Comment: Well, in mobile layouts I want a vertically stacked nav bar, and in desktop layouts I want a horizontal navbar which is why I have the `hidden-xs-small` to hide the horizontal nav and replace it with a collapsible nav in mobile layouts. Lastly, I want to enable scroll spy. Only thing I'm trying to hunt down is what exactly is causing scroll spy to fail. Probably the best plan of attack is to create the navbar from scratch and then enable scroll spy. With scroll spy working I will add back some custom css and if it stops working I will know what css conflicts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114389/discussion-between-tony-chiboucas-and-harish).